# Trigger multiple download on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to trigger multiple download's on a page using js/jquery?

The individual downloads are done using the js  download attribute. the page has multiple such download links and wants to trigger all of them using a global download all

```
<a class="btn btn-download download-1" download="1.txt" href="#"> Download 1 </a><br>
<a class="btn btn-download download-1" download="2.txt" href="#"> Download 2 
</a><br>
<a class="btn btn-download download-1" download="3.txt" href="#"> Download 3 </a><br>

<button class="btn btn-download-all download-1" onClick='downloadAll()'> Download All </button>

$("a.btn-download").click(function(){
this.href = "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8, Some Text" ;
});

function downloadAll(){
$( "a.btn-download" ).trigger( "click" );
}
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u0jhaaL3/6/

Comment: I guess the first question I have is, does the single download work?

Comment: So, when the first one is triggered, and the user is presented with a dialog asking where to save the file, what happens when the user hasn't closed that dialog before the second one is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

You're correctly triggering the click of each button. The problem is that you're triggering the click **before** setting the `href`, so nothing is actually **happening** when you click on each of the downloads.

To resolve this, you'll need to run `this.click()` **again** in your click handler for each of the download links. Unfortunately this would mean that if you were to click on a **singular** download would download that file twice, but this can be resolved by passing a second argument to **[`.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** that indicates that you're attempting to download multiple files. This can the be checked in your function called on click of the individual links, but you'll need to make use of **[`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)** rather than **[`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)** so you can check against the second function parameter.

This can be seen in the following working example:

```js
$("a.btn-download").on("click", function(e, multiple) {
  this.href = "data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8, Some Text";
  if (multiple == 'multiple') {
    this.click();
  }
});

function downloadAll() {
  $("a.btn-download").trigger("click", ['multiple']);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-download download-1" download="1.txt" href="#"> Download 1 </a><br>
<a class="btn btn-download download-1" download="2.txt" href="#"> Download 2 </a><br>
<a class="btn btn-download download-1" download="3.txt" href="#"> Download 3 </a><br>

<button class="btn btn-download-all download-1" onClick='downloadAll()'> Download All </button>
```

Note that you'll be **warned** that you're attempting to download multiple files, so if you want to avoid this, you'd be better off zipping the files.

Comment: Yikes. I didn't realize 'download' was treated differently from 'href' for this purpose.

Comment: ^ I'm sure there's **plenty** of security issues associated with this, but it proves that it's possible. At least you get the warning when your browser attempts to automatically download multiple files! ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm amazed this is allowed. And even more amazed that it isn't being constantly abused.  (I don't even get a warning in MacOS Safari -- it just goes ahead and downloads them.)

Answer (score 0):

### Dynamically generate a zip download

- https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/
- https://github.com/Stuk/jszip

Working example based on your code:

```js
$('a.btn-download').click(function() {
  this.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8, Some Text';
});

function downloadAll() {
  var zip = new JSZip();

  $('a.btn-download').each(function() {
    zip.file(this.download, this.text);
  });

  zip.generateAsync({
    type: 'blob'
  }).then(
    function(blob) {
      saveAs(blob, 'all.zip');
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.5/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn-download" download="1.txt" href="#">Download 1</a><br>
<a class="btn-download" download="2.txt" href="#">Download 2</a><br>
<a class="btn-download" download="3.txt" href="#">Download 3</a><br>

<button class="btn-download-all" onclick='downloadAll()'>Download All</button>
```

[image: Result of clicking on Download All]